# Isotope: append each image after loading (in chronological order)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-isotope

Several days ago I tried to incorporate Isotope into my site, and combine it with Fancybox 2 to create a nice looking gallery with filtering/sorting possibilities. Since many pages contain a lot of images, I prefer to show and append each image directly after it has finished loading rather than showing a loader until all images have been loaded.

In order to achieve this, I came up with this piece of code so far:

```
    $( function() {
  // init isotope  
  var $container = $('.isotope_container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope_image',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    transitionDuration: '0.7s'
  });

// reveal initial images
$container.isotopeImagesReveal($('#images_container').find('.isotope_image'));
});

$.fn.isotopeImagesReveal = function( $items ) {
  var iso = this.data('isotope');
 var itemSelector = iso.options.itemSelector;
  // hide by default
  $items.hide();
  // append to container
  this.append( $items );
  $items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
    // get item
    // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
    var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
    // un-hide item
    $item.show();
    // isotope does its thing
    iso.appended( $item );
  });

  return this;
};

});
```

The code above already does to some extent what I am after. It 'pulls' the images initially present in the `<div id='images_container'>`, and appends an item to isotope once an image has finished loading. The problem however is that the code appends and shows images *in the order they finish loading* (image loaded first becomes #1 in grid, then #2 etc.). Adding the sortby parameter to the isotope options does not work, as the images are not loaded at the point isotope is initiated. Re-sorting them with isotope after all images have been appended this way is possible, but looks very messy.

What I would like to achieve is to have the images *loaded in the order they are present in the `<div id='images_container'>`*. Chronologically when it comes to the original document order so to say. So basically start loading image 1, show and append it once it has been loaded. Then proceed to image 2, show and append it after loading, etc. until all images have been processed.

I think the solution is to alter the `$.fn.isotopeImagesReveal` function to process each of the div items in chronological order, but I can't figure out how.

**Update: added example of current code. http://codepen.io/micksanders/pen/KwXmwO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to add a sorting field to your markup. I added a `data-order="xxxx"` attribute to all elements with the `.isotope_image` class, like so:

```
<div class='isotope_image' data-order="1">
<p>1</p>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports'>
</div>
...
```

Then you need to add that sorting field to your isotope initialisation code... both the `getSortData` and `sortBy` options are needed:

```
var $container = $('.isotope_container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope_image',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    transitionDuration: '0.7s',
    getSortData: {
      order: "[data-order]"
    },
    sortBy: 'order'
  });
```

Finally at the end of your `imagesLoaded.progress()` function, use `iso.insert($item)` instead of `iso.appended($item)`.

Here's the full amended code:
http://codepen.io/BenStevens/pen/MYEmBb

Comment: Doesn't seem to load them in any consistent order. Each time I reload I get a different order 1243, 4231, 2341, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, for me the example above works very nicely! I had to modify it just a little bit to get it working with my data.@Macsupport are you sure the example Ben provided still fails to load them in any consistent order? I checked his example in IE, Firefox, Chrome and on Android, and it seems to work without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function() {

  var $container = $('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 200  
    }
  });

  $('#load-images').click( function() {
    var $items = getItems();
    $container.isotopeImagesReveal( $items );
  });

});

$.fn.isotopeImagesReveal = function( $items ) {
  var iso = this.data('isotope');
  var itemSelector = iso.options.itemSelector;
  // hide by default
  $items.hide();
  // append to container
  this.append( $items );
  $items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
    // get item
    // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
    var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
    // un-hide item
    $item.show();
    // isotope does its thing
    iso.appended( $item );
  });

  return this;
};

function randomInt( min, max ) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * max + min );
}

function getItem() {
  var width = randomInt( 150, 400 );
  var height = randomInt( 150, 250 );
  var item = '<div class="item">'+
    '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/' + 
      width + '/' + height + '/nature" /></div>';
  return item;
}

function getItems() {
  var items = '';
  for ( var i=0; i < 12; i++ ) {
    items += getItem();
  }
  // return jQuery object
  return $( items );
}
```

[See reveal each image as they load](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bsHix)